# What are all the custom URL schemes supported by the Workplace by Facebook iPhone app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-workplace, custom-url-protocol

I am trying to open a group page in Workplace by Facebook app, unfortunately I did not find any custom URL scheme to do it like for the Facebook app.

Does anyone have more information about the custom url schema that can be sent to the Workplace by Facebook app for iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had the same issue and found out that the main url scheme for Workplace is `fbatwork`.

To open the app straight to a group, the only working format on iOS seems to be

```
fbatwork://group?id=your-group-id
```

There are also a few more available, but I don't know exactly what's their purpose: `fbatworksso`, `fbatworksignup`, `fbatworkssoreauth`, `fb-work-emailless`